# Adding a button or link breaks form

Tags: c#, webforms

I am using a windows form and within the form i have a user control with two labels, one that has a message ENTER AMOUNT and the other where I am putting the values typed by the user (like when you go to an ATM) it starts showing the number .. it works fine if i dont have any other controls on the user control.. but the moment i add a button it does not work, it wont start showing the numbers as I use my numeric key pad.. but if i remove whatever button i added it works again... Here is my user control code.

```
 public partial class OperationAmount : UserControl
    {
        public OperationAmount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int _inputNumber = 0;

        private void OperationAmount_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form_KeyAmountPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (lblOperationAmount.Text.Length > 9)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _inputNumber = 10 * _inputNumber + Int32.Parse(e.KeyChar.ToString());
                ReformatOutput();
            }
        }

        private void ReformatOutput()
        {
            lblOperationAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", (double)_inputNumber / 100.0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the new control steals the keypresses from your Form_KeyAmountPressed method because now it has the focus and receive the event KeyPress.
A simple workaround would be to add the method `Form_KeyAmountPressed` also at the KeyPress event of the button. Try also to set the TabStop property of the button to false. (not sure if this has any effect when the button is the only control that can get focus on your user control).